# Accessing out of range word in spaCy doc : why does it work?

Tags: python, nlp, spacy, matcher, pos-tagger

I'm learning spaCy and am playing with [Matchers](https://spacy.io/usage/rule-based-matching).

I have:

- a very basic sentence ("white shepherd dog")
- a matcher object, searching for a pattern ("white shepherd")
- a print to show the match, and the word and POS before that match

I just wanted to check how to handle the index out of range exception I'm expecting to get because there's nothing before the match. I didn't expect it to work, but it did and is returning 'dog', which is after the match... and now I'm confused.

It looks like spaCy uses a circular list (or deque I think) ?

This needs a language model to run, you can install it with the following command line, if you'd like to reproduce it:

`python -m spacy download en_core_web_md`

And this is the code

```
import spacy
from spacy.matcher import Matcher 

# Loading language model
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_md")

# Initialising with shared vocab
matcher = Matcher(nlp.vocab)

# Adding statistical predictions
matcher.add("DOG", None, [{"LOWER": "white"}, {"LOWER": "shepherd"}])  # searching for white shepherd
doc = nlp("white shepherd dog")

for match_id, start, end in matcher(doc):
    span = doc[start:end]  
    print("Matched span: ", span.text)   
    # Get previous token and its POS
    print("Previous token: ", doc[start - 1].text, doc[start - 1].pos_) # I would expect the error here
```

I get the following:

```
>>> Matched span:  white shepherd
>>> Previous token:  dog PROPN
```

Can someone explain what's going on ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for a token at index 0-1 which evaluated to -1, which is the last token.

I recommend using the `Token.nbor` method to look for the first token before the span, and if no previous token exists make it None or an empty string.

```
import spacy
from spacy.matcher import Matcher 

# Loading language model
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_md")

# Initialising with shared vocab
matcher = Matcher(nlp.vocab)

# Adding statistical predictions
matcher.add("DOG", None, [{"LOWER": "white"}, {"LOWER": "shepherd"}])  # searching for white shepherd
doc = nlp("white shepherd dog")

for match_id, start, end in matcher(doc):
    span = doc[start:end]
    print("Matched span: ", span.text)
    try:
        nbor_tok = span[0].nbor(-1)
        print("Previous token:", nbor_tok, nbor_tok.pos_)
    except IndexError:
        nbor_tok = ''
        print("Previous token: None None")
```